# Reading first row as Header from Excel File (slow)

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to read `first row` of Excel File (.xlsb) format. Which are the `column headers`
I have done my research on SO and website. But which ever code I tried. The reading time for first row is about `1:05min`.
Yes I do have around 88 columns in that Excel file.

Now the code which I have found is

```
 String constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
 con.Open();
 Console.Write("Start: "+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
 DataTable dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new object[] { null, null, SheetName, null });
 Console.Write("Ended: "+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
```

**Question**
Is this the best way to proceed. Or should I try a different code. Any suggestions will be appreciated.  Regards

Comment: Do some analysis on your code. Which bits of code take the most time? is it the `con.Open()` line or the `con.GetOleDbSchemaTable`.

Comment: @ElectricLlama from `Start` to `Ended` the line in between takes `1min`

Comment: This very similar post indicates that it may run quicker while the workbook is closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055266/getoledbschematable-sometimes-runs-very-slowly. Is only one table schema returned or many?

Comment: @ElectricLlama I have already achieved my sheet name, which is quick like lighting. When it comes on getting data, either one row or couple its take about 1min. Yes there are many sheets in the Excel Workbook. and Yes my workbook is closed.

Comment: OK I'm just guessing now but maybe you could put more restrictions into the second object array parameter and that might reduce the data that comes back. But really I'm just guessing here.